# Create a Task on Opportunity Only when Opportunity owners are active

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created a trigger which should create a task on opportunities only when opportunity's owner is active.Here is my trigger and helper class:

**Trigger**

```
trigger AutoTaskCreation on Opportunity (before insert, before update, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) { 
           TaskServices.createTaskforOpp(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
```

}

**Helper Class**

```
public with sharing class TaskServices {

public static void createTaskforOpp(List<Opportunity> oppList) {

    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    For(Opportunity opp : oppList) {
      if(opp.Owner.isActive == false) {
      Task newTask = new Task(
           WhatId = opp.Id,
           OwnerId = opp.OwnerId,
           ActivityDate = Date.today(),
          Subject = 'Test Subject',
           Description = 'This a Test'
       );
        taskList.add(newTask);

    }
        }
        insert taskList;
    }
}
```

The above code is creating task for both active and inactive opportunity owners. Why if(opp.Owner.isActive == false) is not working?

Comment: This is a [pretty common problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=trigger+relationship+null), and we regularly get questions like this. The problem is that relationships are not automatically populated in Trigger.new, so you have to query for them.

Comment: N.B. You can't do this in before insert as `opp.Id` will be null

Comment: You don't need `opp.Id` at all, just query the owners directly. But it should be an `after` trigger anyway if you are doing cross-object updates.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger context variables (`Trigger.new`, `Trigger.oldMap`, etc...) do not contain data on related objects, they only contain data for the object the trigger is on.

So, in your helper class, when we get to this line:

```
if(opp.Owner.isActive == false) {
```

`opp.Owner.isActive` is null, null is not equal to false, so your tasks get created.

Technically, `opp.Owner` is null as well, but Salesforce appears to do some magic in the background to prevent this from throwing a Null Pointer Exception.

To have your helper class behave as expected when called from a trigger, you'll need to query the `Opportunities` you  want to pass to your helper class (and explicitly query for Owner.isActive)

```
trigger AutoTaskCreation on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        TaskServices.createTaskforOpp([SELECT Id, OwnerId, Owner.isActive FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you'll also probably want to add a check to see if you've previously generated tasks for a given opportunity. If you don't, you'll have a new task generated _every time an `Opportunity` is updated_. Since you will need to query `Opportunity`, and since you aren't modifying any fields on `Opportunity`, you should be running this code `after insert` and `after update`.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger context records do not contain cross object fields in memory. You have to query for them.

```
Set<Id> allOwnerIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunity record : newRecords)
    allOwnerIds.add(record.OwnerId);
Set<Id> inactiveOwnerIds = new Map<Id, User>([
    SELECT Id FROM User
    WHERE Id IN :allOwnerIds
    AND IsActive = true
]);

for (Opportunity record : newRecords)
{
    if (inactiveOwnerIds.contains(record. OwnerId)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```